# How to test iterator values using google test case?

Tags: c++, googletest

I need to test each iterator access value with actual value inserted using google test case, below is my code snippet.

```
TEST(EVTValSortedVector,  StdIteratorAccess1)
{
EVTValSortedVector<Dog> eTerriers;

eTerriers.insert(Dog("Cairn Terrier",4));
eTerriers.insert(Dog("Irish Terrier",3));
eTerriers.insert(Dog("Schnauzer",3));

EVTValSortedVector<Dog>::iterator i;
for (i = eTerriers.begin(); i != eTerriers.end() ; i++ ) {
//  EXPECT_EQ((i), "Cairn Terrier"); // Here i need to check each iterator 
                                      //value with actual value inserted(here i wrote sample for only one element)
}
}
```

Above in commented line i need to test each inserted value with iterator value, I am new to this google test case, Please help me to resolve this.

I updated my code according to the "Caleth" suggestion, i am getting error for this, i am new to this google test, please suggest, This is my updated code

```
TEST(EVTValSortedVector,  StdIteratorAccess1)
{
EVTValSortedVector<Dog> eTerriers;

eTerriers.insert(Dog("Cairn Terrier",4));
eTerriers.insert(Dog("Irish Terrier",3));
eTerriers.insert(Dog("Schnauzer",3));

EXPECT_EQ(eTerriers[0], "Cairn Terrier");
EXPECT_EQ(eTerriers[1], "Irish Terrier");
EXPECT_EQ(eTerriers[2], "Schnauzer");
}
```

I am getting below error for this, Please suggest.

testEVTValSortedVector.cpp:193: error: no match for ‘operator[]’ in ‘eTerriers[0]’
testEVTValSortedVector.cpp:193: error: template argument 1 is invalid
testEVTValSortedVector.cpp:194: error: no match for ‘operator[]’ in ‘eTerriers[1]’testEVTValSortedVector.cpp:194: error: no match for ‘operator[]’ in ‘eTerriers[1]’testEVTValSortedVector.cpp:195: error: no match for ‘operator[]’ in ‘eTerriers[2]’testEVTValSortedVector.cpp:195: error: no match for ‘operator[]’ in ‘eTerriers[2]’

Comment: *i << this is inserted value.
*i is class Dog object.

Comment: I need to test each iterator value with actual inserted value.

Comment: You need to explain what you expect the iterator values to be.

Comment: Iteration starts from first value(i ="Cairn Terrier"), after increment "i" value (i ="Irish Terrier" ) same thing continues. Here i need to test each iteration value with inserted value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any loop you write is going to be executed for all the cases. Don't write a loop.

```
EXPECT_EQ(eTerriers[0], "Cairn Terrier");
EXPECT_EQ(eTerriers[1], "Irish Terrier");
EXPECT_EQ(eTerriers[2], "Schnauzer");
```

Note that this test doesn't really tell you that the `EVTValSortedVector` maintains a sorted order, you have started with sorted input.

A better test would be to search adjacent elements to see if there is an element earlier in the list that is `>=` a later element.

```
// If we find no adjacent pair of elements `elemN, elemM` such that `elemN >= elemM`, then the list is in ascending order
EXPECT_EQ(std::adjacent_find(eTerriers.begin(), eTerriers.end(), std::greater_eq<Dog>{}), eTerriers.end());
```

This tests `eTerriers` without knowing *anything* about the data you start with, which means that it can be *generated* as part of the test setup. This is a kind of [property based test](http://blog.jessitron.com/2013/04/property-based-testing-what-is-it.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i didn't get how to use array for my code, can you please suggest.

Comment: @sunil "how to use array"? what array, and why do you want to use it?

Comment: I updated my code according to your suggestion,  please look into that updated code above, it says no matching operator for [], i am bit confused with arrays, i am new to this, thanks for your help so far and looking forward for the suggestion.

Comment: You must show what is EVTValSortedVector. Obviously whatever this type is, it has no operator [] defined

Comment: @sunil I was assuming that something named `EVTValSortedVector` would have vector-like members, such as an `operator[]`

Comment: Thanks a lot @Caleth